# Replace string per variable in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, python-3.10

I'm new at Robot Framework and I'm working with a REST API. I'm trying to replace a string inside a json per a variable so I can use an environment variable in my Post and Put methods.

```
{"key1":"value1",
 "key2": {"key3: "value3"}}
```

I need to replace the value of "value1" and the value of "value3" per a variable like %{value3}. How can I do this in Robot Framework?

Thanks!

Comment: The Collections Library has keyword [Set to Dictionary](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Set%20To%20Dictionary). What have you attempted and why has it not worked?

Comment: I have tried Set to Dictionary but I don't need to add a new item on this dict, I need to replace a value inside of him. I have tried to use replace() from Python and its not working.